# As3 How do I add acceleration to limited movement?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, bitmapdata, bounds, maze

For a maze game, I'm trying to add acceleration to the movement of my character.
Because the character shouldn't walk through walls, the movement function and hittest are in the same function.

I tried adding the acceleration in if statements in this function, but that doesn't work properly. 
Can anyone tell me where to put the acceleration code, and why there?

This is how I thought it was done, but doesn't work:

```
    function walkingX(anEvent: Event): void
    {


      var newx: Number = mc.x - (isLeft ? xspeed : 0) + (isRight ? xspeed : 0);
      var newy: Number = mc.y - (isUp ? yspeed : 0) + (isDown ? yspeed : 0);

      if(!boundsBmpData.hitTest(new Point(bounds.x, bounds.y),
                                255,
                                mcBmpData,
                                new Point(newx, newy),
                                255))
      {
         mc.x = newx;
         mc.y = newy;
      }

if(isDown==true && yspeed<maxspeed){yspeed+=2}
if(isUp==true && yspeed>-maxspeed){yspeed-=2}
if(yspeed>0){yspeed-=accel}
if(yspeed<0){yspeed+=accel}

if(isRight==true && xspeed<maxspeed){xspeed+=2}
if(isLeft==true && xspeed>-maxspeed){xspeed-=2}
if(xspeed>0){xspeed-=accel}
if(xspeed<0){xspeed+=accel}

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove these lines:

```
if(yspeed>0){yspeed-=accel}
if(yspeed<0){yspeed+=accel}
...
...
...
if(xspeed>0){xspeed-=accel}
if(xspeed<0){xspeed+=accel}
```

Reason being it subtracts from the logic above it.

Regarding **acceleration**, you probably don't want to increment your speed value by a constant of "2". I would put that into a variable or static declared above (so you can change it just in one place instead of everywhere it's used.

Last, to get that "acceleration" effect, you should increase the speed by multiply by a fraction.

Like this:

```
if(isDown==true && yspeed<maxspeed){yspeed *= 1.05}
```

Or with the static constant

```
public static const MOVEMENT_SPEED:int = 1.05;
...
...
...
if(isDown==true && yspeed<maxspeed){yspeed *= MOVEMENT_SPEED}
```

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation. So I don't even need var accel:Number=0.5; ?

Comment: Can you tell me why this doesnt work: if(isDown==true && yspeed<maxspeed){yspeed *= acceleration}

Comment: You can use var accel:Number=1.5 (or 1.1 or 1.05). The bug issues from your acceleration value, which means you're multiplying by 0.5. That value, if you think about it will DECREASE your speed (what's half of 10? 5. what's half of 5? 2.5) as opposed by multiply by 1.5 (what's one AND a half of 10? 15)

Comment: Umm, no, do NOT multiply xspeed/yspeed with a number. Add a number to it, not multiply!!! It should not exponentially increase.

Comment: Arithmetic vs Linear progression... it's whatever he wants.